# VS2017 "restore packages" restores 80 packages. "nuget.exe restore" restores 64 packages

Tags: nuget

Struggling with getting a solution of 50+ projects to build in Jenkins. The first thing Jenkins does is `nuget.exe restore my.sln` before running msbuild (failing because packages are missing).

If I erase the packages folder locally and have Visual Studio recreate it (right click solution, choose "restore packages") then 80 packages appear on my dev machine

If I erase the packages folder on the build server and then call the same `nuget.exe restore` from the command line, that Jenkins is configured to call, then only 64 packages are restored

Answer (score 0):

I came across the solution while writing up the question; classic cardboard analysis.

I was intending to write "using nuget restore on the same solution.." and then I thought; are they the same solution?

Turned out, someone had added another solution to the source code repository, and configured Jenkins to call nuget restore on that, so I was effectively calling restore on different solutions:

- VS2017 has the `My.sln` open, and restores 80 packages
- Jenkins is configured with a build process that calls `nuget.exe restore My-subset.sln` and restores 64 packages

The repo file/folders structure is:

```
source/
+- files and folders
+- My.sln
+- My-subset.sln
+- My-othersubset.sln …
```

**TLDR**: make sure you're restoring on the same solutions! :)